# Simultaneous similarity classes of pairs in $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}$Let $G$ be an elementary abelian $p$-group of rank $2$. Let $\alpha, \beta :G\rightarrow \GL_{n}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)$ be two injective homomorphisms. The homomorphisms $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are called similar if there exist $\sigma \in {\rm Aut}(A)$, $\rho \in{\rm Aut}(G)$ such that $(\beta \circ \rho )(g)=\sigma \circ \alpha (g)\circ \sigma^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are injective then $\alpha(G)$ and $\beta(G)$ are elementary abelian p-subgroups of rank 2 in $GL_{n}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)$.Thus, set $\alpha(G)=\langle A,B\rangle$ and $\beta(G)=\langle A',B'\rangle$ for some $A$ ,$B$ ,$A'$ and $B'\in \GL_{n}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)$.

The pairs $(A,B)$ and $(A',B')$ are called **simultaneously similar** if there is $U\in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb F_p)$ such that $A'=UAU^{-1}$, $B'=UBU^{-1}$.

Are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ similar homomorphisms if and only if the pairs $(A,B)$ and $(A',B')$ are simultaneously similar?.

What is the number of simultaneous similarity classes of the pair $(A,B)$ in $GL_{n}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)$?.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems implicit that $A,B$ are the images of two given generators of $G$ (rather than an arbitrary generating pair of $\alpha(G)$, as the current notation seems to indicate)? Also $A$ is used to denote a group, and then to denote a matrix.

Comment: @YCor. You're right. A, B are the images of two given generators of G.

Comment: But what is $A$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$. Probably not the image of the first generator, also denoted $A$.

Comment: I am not sure whether I am understanding the definitions properly, and you need to sort out your notation, but it looks as thought the pairs $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$ could fail to be simultaneously similar, but the corresponding homomorphisms $\alpha, \beta$ would be similar, because there is an automorphism of $\langle A,B \rangle$ that swaps $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I added some clarifications to the question. @YCor of course I m not loking to A as image of the first generator of G. In fact, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are similar it follows that $\alpha(G)$ and $\beta(G)$ are conjugate subgroup which led to the simultaneous similarity of their generators.

Comment: So you're using $A$ for two different things; it seems that $A$ denotes $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})$ at the beginning, and the image of the first generator (hence a given element of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})$) later. Why don't you fix it?

Comment: @Derek Holt, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are similar, it follows that $\alpha(G)$ and $\beta(G)$ are conjugate subgroup in $ GL_{n}(\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z)$ which led to the simultaneous similarity of their generators.

Comment: No, it doesn't, you should read Derek's comment more carefully.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Maybe I didn't understand it very well,  or I missed some think.  what do you think about the second question?.